# Design Issue with Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, spinner

[image]
[image]

I am creating a layout for my dialog box.
In Android Studio the layout is showing the EditText and spinner in normal Android 4.0+ like design(see,image 2)

But when I am deploying this app on my mobile running Android 5.0, the edittext and spinner design seems like as in Android Gingerbread (2.3).

I don't know what is the issue, and why this design is messing up.

This is my AndroidManifest code

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.random.DialogAmountEdit"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"></activity>
```

and this is my styles.xml code

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: Can you show us your `AndroidManifest.xml` and `styles.xml`? It might be a styling / theme issue.

Comment: I have edited the code above.You may have a look

Answer (score 0):

Did you use DialogFragments ?
The missing part will be the setStyle call then. You have to do this before the Fragment gets shown.

```
@NonNull
public static SlowConnectionDialogFragment newInstance(final String errorText) {
    final Bundle bundle = BundleArgs.create(errorText);
    final SlowConnectionDialogFragment instance = new SlowConnectionDialogFragment();
    instance.setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_Dialog);
    instance.setArguments(bundle);
    return instance;
}
```

For Dialogs are some kind of other Styling properties needed, to get the floating window back. So you should consider creating another theme for Dialogs.

Comment: I am not using this as DialogFragment. I have created a simple Activity for dialog and then using startActivityResult to pass the value back and forth between activities